# XmlHttpRequest with asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, web, xmlhttprequest

I try to send a get request to my ashx file.But I have character problem.  
Problem is when I send request by firefox or crome no problem but when try to send with IE I cant  
 get what I send. I send "Ç" character but on server side i cant get it.

```
myRequest.open("GET", "/Search.ashx?SearchText=" + search + "", true);
myRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myRequest.send(null);
```

Comment: Did you try `myRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");` ?

Comment: yes i did it, but this is for content encode, i need to encode URL

Comment: Give a try to : `var myEncodedUrl = "/Search.ashx?SearchText=" + encodeURIComponent(search); myRequest.open("GET", myEncodedUrl, true);`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you haven't encoded 'search' string with encodeURIComponent function using javascript. On ashx side, you can use HttpUtility.HTMLDecode method to decode your string.

Comment: hi, thanks for your advice but dont show me how i catch fish , give to me a fish

Answer (score 1):

encodeURIComponent(search) is answer.